# reduce expansionTile height in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, height, expansion

is there a way to reduce the height of the ExpansionTile header because it doesn't have a height property,
after searching i found [this](https://gist.github.com/diegoveloper/02424eebd4d6e06ae649b31e4ebcf53c) on github for a custom color but i cannot modify it to add a height property
besides it gives me errors say " drive is not defined for the class AnimationController"

Comment: Any one know how to get it done?

Comment: Have you tried https://pub.dev/packages/configurable_expansion_tile It worked for me

Comment: please add it as an answer so i can mark it as the correct one

Comment: Alright man, will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [Configurable Expansion Tile](https://pub.dev/packages/configurable_expansion_tile) from dart's dev site. Its really customizable and worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 18):

```
ListTileTheme(
  dense: true,
  child: ExpansionTile(..),
..
```

how about this?

Comment: Hurrah! Worked for me.